# web URL, document.querysellector

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am facing problem to get current url here is my code

```
Sub CheckJDName()
Dim Url As String
Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument

Url = "https://www.justdial.com/Hansi/Beauty-Parlours"

        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", Url, False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .Send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            S = .responseText
        End With

        Set html = New HTMLDocument
        Dim storesTextToDecipher As Object

        With html
            .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = html.querySelector("head > link:nth-child(50)").href
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End With

End Sub
```

here I am facing problem invalid argument

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = html.querySelector("head > link:nth-child(50)").href
```

please help me out

Comment: What type of a question is this? You didn't even specify the field you wish to grab from that webpage.

Comment: Sorry Sir... actually I want to grab currant URL,

Comment: So far I can recall pseudo selectors like `:nth-child()`, `:nth-of-type()` e.t.c supports within `.querySelector()` when you use the latter within IE.

Comment: Sir want to grab canonical url link.. that  href is in doccument head part..  please if you can write code for me as i am not more aware of VBA and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab the canonical url from that page you need to kick out the comment signs around it first. Given that this is how you can grab it.

```
Sub GrabCanonicalUrl()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.justdial.com/Hansi/Beauty-Parlours"
    Dim S$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        S = Replace(Replace(.responseText, "<!--", ""), "-->", "")
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        MsgBox .querySelector("link[rel='canonical']").getAttribute("href")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks you so much sir its a perfect what i want.. real great solution

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Please sir if you can look in my another question[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62232565/vba-for-web-scraping)