# Getting meta proper content from url

Tags: vba

I am trying to get meta proper content from url but facing some problem

i want to grab "og:url" content detail, here is my code

```
 Sub GrabCanonicalUrl3()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.justdial.com/Ambala/Beauty-Parlours-in-Naraingarh"
    Dim S$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .Send
        S = Replace(Replace(.responseText, "<!--", ""), "-->", "")
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        MsgBox .querySelector("meta[property='og:url']").getAttribute("content")
    End With
End Sub
```

facing this earror

> Object variable or block variable not set

```
MsgBox .querySelector("meta[property='og:url']").getAttribute("content")
```

I want to get url (og:url) link from inner HTML . but not

please help me out

Comment: _i am facing problem here_ <== What problem do you face? Please be more specific.

Comment: facing this earror   Object variable or block variable not set

Comment: Please add this to the post

Comment: yes Sir I added into the post

Comment: Next question: What do you expect to get with `.querySelector("meta[property='og:url']").getAttribute("content")`. And it's best you add this to the post as well.

Comment: added Sir in to post

Comment: Did you look at `.body.innerHTML` and does it contain what you want to get?

Comment: its not part in body it part in head

Comment: My assumption is that `.querySelector("meta[property='og:url']")` isn't getting set as your query into the DOM with the `querySelector` method is failing. I would separate out that logic and set a variable to hold the output of the `querySelector` method that you can inspect with an `if` statement before trying to dig into it for your `getAttribute("content")` method. If it's not set, it's going to be bomb on that step. Essentially what you are saying with `MsgBox .querySelector("meta[property='og:url']").getAttribute("content")` is that you anticipate that `.querySelector` isn't going to fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim obj As Object, sResp As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.xmlHttp")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.justdial.com/Ambala/Beauty-Parlours-in-Naraingarh", False
        .send
        sResp = .responseText
    End With
    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write sResp
        For Each obj In .all(2).getElementsByTagName("meta")
            If obj.getAttribute("Property") = "og:url" Then Debug.Print obj.Content: Exit For
        Next obj
    End With
End Sub
```